# Efficiently Evaluate a Multivariable Function on a List of Tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a function `G[x,y,z,r,s,t]` in the code below.  Quite simply, I want to generate a list of all possible tuples $(x,y,z,r,s,t)$ such that all six entries are taken from the set $\{0,1,2,...,N-1\}$ where $N$ will be an integer parameter of the problem.  I then want to evaluate $G$ on each of these tuples and as efficiently as I can, count the number of the tuples which evaluate to 0 *modulo $N$*.  I at least have the following:

`G[x_, y_, z_, r_, s_, t_] := 
  x*y*z*(r^3 + s^3 + t^3) - r*s*t*(x^3 + y^3 + z^3);
F[N_] := Range[0, N - 1];
Tup[N_] := Tuples[F[N], 6];`

So `Tup[N]` is a list of all my tuples of interest.  I was about to do a "for loop" ranging over the number of tuples and evaluate something like

`G[Tup[2][[4]][[1]], Tup[2][[4]][[2]], Tup[2][[4]][[3]], 
 Tup[2][[4]][[4]], Tup[2][[4]][[5]], Tup[2][[4]][[6]]]`

for example, but this seems to be extremely inefficient.  I'm sure there must be a smarter way!  So given my `G[x,y,z,r,s,t]` as well as `Tup[N]` how can I construct a function `P[N]` which will output the number of tuples which evaluate to 0 modulo $N$?

Comment: Try `G @@@ Tup[10];` or `G @@ Transpose[Tup[10]];`. The latter should be faster but may not always work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are several ways to perform the computations along with timings:

```
G2[X_] := X[[1]] X[[2]] X[[3]] (X[[4]]^3 + X[[5]]^3 + X[[6]]^3) - 
   X[[4]] X[[5]] X[[6]] (X[[1]]^3 + X[[2]]^3 + X[[3]]^3);
cG2 = With[{code = G2[Array[Compile`GetElement[X, #] &, {6}]]},
   Compile[{{X, _Integer, 1}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];


data = Tup[10];
a = G @@@ data; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = G @@ Transpose[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = G2 /@ data; // RepeatedTiming // First
d = cG2[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
e = Flatten[Outer[G, ## & @@ ConstantArray[F[10], 6]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c == d == e
```

> 4.012
>
> 0.068
>
> 7.30
>
> 0.0312
>
> 3.80
>
> True

Comment: wow, the compilation really does rule! any insight on why `a` and `b` have such differing runtimes?

Comment: Well, `b` heavily uses vectorization and `d` is compiled. So, `a` and `c` have to struggle with the fact that Mathematica is an interpreted language, not a compiled one. They are also not parallelized. I am a bit surprised that `c` is so much slower than `a`

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks a lot.  I appreciate the multiple solutions.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

```
tup1[N_] := Tuples[G @@ F[N], 6]
```

or

```
tup2[N_] := Flatten[Outer[G, ## & @@ ConstantArray[F[N], 6]]]
```

They both give the same result as `G @@@ Tup[N]` suggested by Henrik:

```
tup1[7] == tup2[7] == G @@@ Tup[7]
```

> True